# How can I change the Woocommerce shipping method based on a keyword in the checkout page?

Tags: woocommerce, shipping-method

I try to set the Woocommerce shipping method depending on a keyword on the checkout page.

The code what i tried is the following:

```
// Hinzufügen der benutzerdefinierten Funktion zum Ändern der Versandmethode
add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_process', 'change_shipping_method_based_on_text');
function change_shipping_method_based_on_text() {
    // Überprüfen, ob der bestimmte Text auf der Checkout-Seite vorhanden ist
    if (strpos($_POST['post_data'], 'KEYWORD') !== false) {
        // Ändern der Versandmethode entsprechend der Versand-ID
        $shipping_id = '4';
        
        // Überprüfen, ob die Versand-ID gültig ist
        $shipping_method = WC()->shipping->get_shipping_method($shipping_id);
        
        if ($shipping_method) {
            WC()->session->set('chosen_shipping_methods', array($shipping_id));
        }
    }
}
```

https://beef.tirol

But it does not work. Any ideas?

I tried to change the keyword and also the beginning capitalzied letter, but no way...

Answer (score 0):

Here is improved version with few comments why

The `woocommerce_before_checkout_process` action hook is not the appropriate hook to use for modifying the shipping method. This hook is fired before the payment is processed, and it is not intended for modifying the shipping methods. You should consider using a different hook, such as `woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping` .

```
add_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping', 'change_shipping_method_based_on_text');
function change_shipping_method_based_on_text() {
    $keyword = 'KEYWORD'; // Specify the keyword you are checking for
    
    // Check if the keyword is present in the posted data
    if (strpos($_POST['post_data'], $keyword) !== false) {
        // Change the shipping method based on the shipping ID
        $shipping_id = '4';
        
        // Check if the shipping ID is valid
        $shipping_method = WC()->shipping->get_shipping_method($shipping_id);
        
        if ($shipping_method) {
            // Set the chosen shipping method for the current session
            WC()->session->set('chosen_shipping_methods', array($shipping_id));
        }
    }
}
```